# Best approach to adding integers in nested lists if they share a common string element?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, algorithm, sorting

The problem I have is I need to add/substract monomials in a polynomial equation
e.g. `2xy+abc-xy -> xy+abc`.
So far I've approached this by extracting the various elements for each monomial using regex and placing them in a list of lists. Using the above example would look like this:

```
[['+', '2', 'xy', 2], ['+', '3', 'abc', 3], ['-', '1', 'xy', 2]]
```

> The fourth element in each list is just the length of the third element I'm retaining for sorting once the equation is reassembled.

Currently, I'm iteratively adding each value to a dictionary before pulling the result.
Pseudocode for brevity:

```
if string not in dict:
    dict[string] = num
else:
    dict[string] += num
result = [str(num) + string for item in dict.items]
```

I'm convinced there has to be a more efficient way of solving it.
Routes explored so far:

- comparing lists with `set()`, `cmp()`
- using `reduce()` or `zip`, which I regretably don't know how to use well
- using `filter()` to return lists with matching elements
- lots of searching on SO

First question on stack overflow, any advice or pointers in the right direction most appreciated.

EDIT:
For anyone curious, this is how I went about this particular section of the task. Thanks everyone for the pointers.

```
pattern = r"([+-]|)([\d]+|)([a-z]+)"
monomial_dict = {}
# poly = "-a+5ab+3a-c-2a"
for m in re.finditer(pattern, poly): 
        mono_val = m.group(2)
        if not mono_val: # if no num in front of monomial, make equal to 1 for dict addition
            mono_val = '1'
        num = int(m.group(1) + mono_val)
        string = ''.join(sorted(m.group(3)))
        if string not in monomial_dict:
            monomial_dict[string] = [num, string]
        else:
            monomial_dict[string][0] += num
# monomial_dict = {'a': [0, 'a'], 'ab': [5, 'ab'], 'c': [-1, 'c']}
```

Comment: Your Pseudocode looks like an O(n) solution. You cannot get better than than because you need to read the hole input which needs O(n). Depending on the implementation of the dictionary HashMap sorted map ... there might be a bit extra complexity.

Comment: A google search yielded sympy. It could be a useful library. But as others have said, better than O(n) can't be done. They may however have a cleaner implementation.

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/87586/equation-parser-and-solver This doesn't exactly match your use case but may help.

Comment: Thank you all for the feedback. Sympy does look like it would help with this a lot but unfortunately I couldn't use it for the task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think at best you could skip the 'list of lists' step and accumulate the matches in the dictionary when iterating over the regex matches.

The current approach with the dictionary should already be quite efficient, as it scales O(n) with the size of the list.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I was using `re.findall(r"([+-]|)([\d]+|)([a-z]+)", poly)` which just returns a list. After reading your comment, I came across `re.finditer()` which returns each match sequentially and should allow me to put things into the dictionary more easily. Will update OP if I find anything else worth sharing.